react-datepicker calendar popper not taking proper position due to ag-grid table view
We are rendering react-datepicker inside ag-grid table field issue is if i pass popperPlacement prop to datepicker it's not affecting in UI any value it's showing same for all position.That's why in some scenarios it's cutting to browser means user unable to see full calendar popper.
I have attached screenshot of popper with ag-grid cell.I have already tried with popper modifiers and popper container nothing works for me.
Note: If i open from middle,left, right any places calendar popper is opening in the same place.
Can anyone kindly suggest me approach for solution is it because of ag-grid or react-datepicker?
Thanks in advance.
